# Add value from combobox onto multiple columns

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have created a combobox that has different cases seen below. The current formula works except that I would like to add a additional column that replicates the same value given to columns C and want to add it column R.

Ex. ComboBox
Select Current Month
I want to add 500 units to Column C and Column R based on the part that was searched for.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim irow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As String
Dim C As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim value As Long
Dim NewPart As Boolean
Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")

Set C = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If C Is Nothing Then
'find first empty row in database
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    irow = lastRow + 1
    NewPart = True
Else
'find row where the part is
    irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    NewPart = False
End If
'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
  Exit Sub
End If



Select Case MonthComboBox.value

    Case "Current Month"

        iCol = "C" And "R"

    Case "Current Month +1"

        iCol = "N"

    Case "Current Month +2"

        iCol = "O"

    Case "Current Month +3"

        iCol = "P"

    Case "Current Month +4"

        iCol = "Q"

End Select
value = Cells(irow, iCol).value
With ws


  .Cells(irow, iCol).value = value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)


End With

If NewPart = True Then
    ws.Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
End If


If NewPart = True Then
 ws.Cells(irow, "C").value = Me.AddTextBox.value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I may recommend using an Array to store the columns.

```
Sub t()
Dim iCol()
Dim testStr$, myValue$
Dim iRow&
Dim ws As Worksheet
testStr = "Current Month"

Select Case testStr
    Case "Current Month"
        iCol() = Array("C", "R")
    Case "Current Month +1"
        iCol() = Array("N")
    End Select

Dim i&
For i = LBound(iCol) To UBound(iCol)
    myValue = Cells(iRow, iCol(i)).value ' WHAT SHEET IS THIS ON??
    With ws
        .Cells(iRow, iCol(i)).value = myValue + CLng(Me.AddTextbox.value)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

You can add to the `Case` as needed.  Note that you need to wrap the `Next i` after you're done working with a column, so it can see if there's a second one to run on.

Also, since you didn't include all the code, you may have to adjust the ranges. (note the `myValue` doesn't have a Sheet specified for what `Cells()` to use).

Comment: @Luis - I'd update your code to include the Array, as in my example.  Just add the `Next i` after your `End With` that ends the `With ws` statement.  Or, after your `If NewPart` sections, if each column will affect that.  Does that make sense?